# Offline install of pytorch fails

Tags: python, pytorch, setuptools

I am trying to install [pytorch (version 2.0.1)](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch) on a machine without internet connection. It fails with a message

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement setuptools
ERROR: No matching distribution found for setuptools
```

I ran

```
grep -r 'setuptools[[:blank:]]*>=' .
```

inside the pytorch directory to determine the minimum required version of setuptools. All I got was that setuptools should be >= 42. The version installed on the system is setuptools version 44. I additionally installed setuptools version 50.3.2 for the user with

```
pip3 install --user .
```

It was successfully installed in $HOME/.local/lib.

However, installation for pytorch still fails with the same error. I have tried the following commands from within the extracted pytorch directory:

```
pip3 install --user .
PYTHONPATH=$HOME/.local pip3 install --user .
PYTHONPATH=$HOME/.local/lib pip3 install --user .
PYTHONPATH=$HOME/.local/lib/python3.9 pip3 install --user .
PYTHONPATH=$HOME/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages pip3 install --user .
```

It still fails with the same error. The OS is:
Devuan, chimaera